# How to mmap in Linux a file under Windows' share (LINUX)?

Tags: c, linux, windows, share, mmap

I am mounting a Windows share in Linux with `-o uid=1000,gid=1000` so no permission problems should appear. I made sure the permissions are set correctly in windows.

I can create, edit, as well as delete directories and files.
However, I cannot mmap a file on the share (on regular mount point it works).

I also cannot fsync directories but this is understandable.

How to mmap the share?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

int main()
{
    const char * file = "/home/lvm/Sources/SharedVM/blabla";

    int fd = open(file, O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_SYNC, S_IWUSR | S_IRUSR);
    printf("%d\n", fd);

    int frc = posix_fallocate(fd, 0, 1024L);
    printf("fallocate rc=%d\n", frc);

    void * result = mmap(0, 1024L, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    printf("errno=%d\n", errno);

    printf("addr = %p\n", result);

    printf("res = %p", result); // => 0xffffffffffffffff when windows share, or valid adddress on linux regular mount point

    return 42;
}
```

Result :

```
3
fallocate rc=0
errno=22
addr = 0xffffffffffffffff
```

While if changing the file to "/tmp/blabla" then we get:

```
3
fallocate rc=0
errno=0
addr = 0x7f9e2de7c000
```

Comment: That is not the errno, that is the return code. Print the actual value of `errno` to see the errno.

Comment: I printed the errno later after submitting this code.. it was -1

Comment: ok.. my bad.  it was "9"

Comment: Let me check my test again..

Comment: I didn't notice I umount the share by mistake.. Now it is re-shared.  I get a valid file descriptor.  The mmap fails with errno = 22.  posix_falloc succeed.

Comment: The only thing I can see that would cause EINVAL would be the length. Try 4096L, 8192L, or 65535L.

Comment: Tried with those 3 values with no help. (I edited the code to be more clear in the question)

Comment: Just regarding the size discussion: The size should be a multiple of the pagesize, which you should can determine using `sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE)`.

Comment: Have you tried to open it with either pure read or pure write privileges? Does this change anything?

Comment: Markus - I tried with no help but I found what was the problem.. The filesystem does not support fallocate...

Answer (score 0):

Well, the answer is the file system does not support fallocate.
The share was cifs.   That's why /tmp file was able to be fallocated.
Sharing ntfs directory works.  cifs doesn't.